# Can we use the Parent Business unit as a child business unit in salesforce marketing cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud, sfmc-business-unit

We have a scenario regarding business units where we want your feedback on this.

Let's take an example:

We have one business unit called **Business unit A(By default - Parent)** where we have already implemented all our configurations, integrations, automation, journeys.

Now somehow our requirement changes and we want to create another business unit called **Business unit B** and we want to make this **Business unit B as a Parent**.

We have researched we can't make the **EID(Business unit A) a child**, we would need to create a new **BU(Business unit B)** and migrate everything there. EID is the only Business Unit that can't have its hierarchy changed. So look like we have to migrate everything in BU(Business unit B) and it will take a good amount of time as it will require the analysis of journey, configuration, etc.

So, we are not going to create BU (Business unit B) as it will be very complex. So what we are thinking to do is that we will use **Business unit A(By default - Parent) Like Child**.

1. Business unit A(By default - Parent) -

- Business unit B (Child 1)
- Business unit C (Child 2)
- Business unit D (Child 3)

So our question is, what are **Pros and Cons** if we use the Parent Business unit as a child business unit? Can we do this? What are the challenges we can face in the future if we will use this approach?

Please help.

Comment: Can you explain why are you trying to do that? And what do you mean by “consider as child bu” and “use as child bu”? Which “child bu functionality” are you missing in your parent bu?

Comment: So, let's take an example. Previously we don't need multiple business units. we have only one business that is in India. 
So we have one BU called "BU-India". Now we have started our business in the US and AUS as well. So we want one parent BU called "BU-Admin" that has several child BU "BU-India","BU-US","BU-AUS" like that. In this case, what we can do?

Comment: Currently, "BU-India" is parent BU (by default) and we can't change into Child BU. So my question is if we consider "BU-India" parent BU (by default) as a child BU. and create another child business "BU-US","BU-AUS". So what will be the impact on "BU-US","BU-AUS".Like Example: "BU-india" will able/control "BU-US","BU-AUS" as well. So that pros and cons I want to understand.